# Vaadin SliderPanel not displaying

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using the Vaadin add-on [SliderPanel](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sliderpanel) (https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sliderpanel) in my project and am having a very hard time making it go away and reappear on the correct view. When I load the application and log in, it correctly takes me to the correct class/page, 'Dashboard', with no SliderPanel. When I navigate to any other class/page which is supposed to re-display the SliderPanel, it does not appear as expected. In order for me to get it to show, I have to resize the window. Same thing happens when I resize the window then go back to the 'Dashboard' page...I have to resize the window and the SliderPanel tab goes away. How can I get the SliderPanel tab to update itself when changing views with the navigator?

In my UI I have **@push()** annotated above the main class.

```
@Push()
public class EvoltwebUI extends UI implements ClickListener {...}
```

Inside the class I have these annotations and servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = EvoltwebUI.class, widgetset = "com.evolt.evoltweb.widgetset.EvoltwebWidgetset")

public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

I've registered the views like this:

```
private void registerViews() {
        navigator.addView("dashboard", DashboardViewImpl.class);
        navigator.addView("groups", GroupsViewImpl.class);
        navigator.addView("research", ResearchViewImpl.class);
        navigator.addView("reporting", ReportsViewImpl.class);
        navigator.addView("execution", AdhocExecView.class);
        navigator.addView("tcreview", TestCaseReviewView.class);
        navigator.addView("toolbox", ToolboxView.class);
    }
```

The 'enter' method on each view/class looks like this:

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    presenter.onViewEnter(event.getParameters());
    generateFields();
    ProgressPanel.setViewName("Test Case Review - Please load a group from the Test Group Explorer Slider Panel on the left.");
    evoltWebUI.getTreeViewSlider().defaultTab();
}
```

I've tried using these, but I am having the same type of issue to where it will not come back if setVisible is false. :

```
leftTreeViewSlider.setVisible(true);
leftTreeViewSlider.setVisible(false);
```

I've also tried extending SliderPanel to access the actual size of the tab to shrink it, but when setting it back to the normal size I have to resize the window to get it back.

```
import org.vaadin.sliderpanel.SliderPanel;
import org.vaadin.sliderpanel.SliderPanelBuilder;    
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;

public class SliderPanelMod extends SliderPanel{

    public SliderPanelMod(SliderPanelBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);

    }

    public void resizeTab(int t) {
        this.getState().tabSize = t; 
    }

    public void defaultTab() {
        resizeTab(40);

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: If you make a SSCCE, I will have a look at it.